# Mac Pro M1 (2022) doesnt charge via USB-C - sometimes

Tags: usb, battery, charging

I have a problem with my Macbook pro M1 14" 2022 model. I use it on my desktop and to combat the issue of few usb (A) ports, I have it connected to a (branded) docking station (Fujitsu USB Port Replicator Model NPR44). To further reduce the need to (dis-)connect cables every time I leave the desk with the computer, I only connect the mac via USB-C to the docking station.

While everything is peachy and works as intended, sometimes (read: every few days and not always) my mac refuses to charge.

- It's not the cable (I tried different ones)
- its not a failing battery (battery health is fine and the mac is quite new)
- its not a failing docking station (it charges everything else just fine and has no problems whatsoever with other computers)

When this happens, un- and replugging the USB-C wont help - also not when using another of the 3 total USB-C ports on the mac.

Restarting the mac will do the trick, but this is quite cumbersome.
Using the magsafe charging cable helps, too, but defeats the whole idea of having only one cable to (dis-) connect the mac.

Anyone knows what to do to avoid this from happening?

Comment: At what % is the battery when it won't charge? Could it be the 80% 'optimised' feature? Also, is this a 16" MBP? The power rating is quite high, and it could be too high for your dock -- (other computers you've tried may have lower ratings).

Comment: Part pf your testing should be to bypass the dock and go directly from a power source to the port (where it presented the issue).  If it goes away, it’s not the Mac

Comment: It's the 14" model. The capacity is at full, typically and then proceeds to fall until empty (after a full working day, for example).

Comment: Does the Battery system preference say that it's charging?

Comment: Well - when it IS charging it does, otherwise not

Comment: What's the dock model? What charging speed does System Profiler show when it's connected?

Comment: What is the System Profiler? System Information doesnt show me anything regarding to battery. The system settings only shows me that the battery health is "normal"

Comment: Dock is a Fujitsu "USB Port Replicator" Model NPR44